# Divide plot into a number of range segments and show the mid-range point of each segment on the curve

Tags: plotting

I have a code here:

```
expr = Sqrt[2]\[Sqrt](\[Sqrt](1/x^2+20 Sqrt[3118] (1/x)^(3/2) 
Sqrt[1/50]+3118020 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/x] (1/50)^(3/2)+24304810001/50^2+ 
623602/(x 50))-10 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/x] Sqrt[1/50]-155900 /50)

(*I use this method here to calculate the midpoint (x,y coordinates) and range of the graph*)
nMax = NMaxValue[expr, {x, 5, 500}];
nMin = NMinValue[expr, {x, 5, 500}];
nR = nMax - nMin;
nRan = nR/4
nRanC = nRan/2
n1 = nMin + nRanC
Solve[expr == n1, x]
n2 = n1 + nRan
Solve[expr == n2, x]
n3 = n2 + nRan
Solve[expr == n3, x]
n4 = n3 + nRan
Solve[expr == n1, x]
(*Then I plot to divide into 4 different section of graph*)
n1x=nMin+nRan
n2x=n1x+nRan
n3x=n2x+nRan
n4x=n3x+nRan
Row[Plot[expr,{x,5,500},MeshFunctions->{#2&},MeshShading->{None,Blue},Mesh->{#},MeshStyle->Opacity[0],PlotRange->{{0,500},{0,1}},AxesLabel->{x,SuperStar[E]},ImageSize->300]&/@{{n3x,n4x},{n2x,n3x},{n1x,n2x},{nMin,n1x}}]
```

The above code is to divide the graph into 4 different section. Meaning that I have to set/calculate the 4 section manually into the code.

Let's say that if I wanted to do `mx=Input["how many graph to show?"]`, then to **calculate the midpoint and range of each graph shown**, and to **plot the graph altogether automatically based on the `mx` value given** (by using some kind of loop?).

How exactly do I do that? I'm kind of new to mathematica and still learning about its use. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No looping isn necessary (You seldom need looping in Mathematica.) Here is how to break your plot into an arbitrary number of vertical sections.

```
expr = 
  (1/5)*Sqrt[
          -155900 - 100*Sqrt[1559]*Sqrt[1/x] + 
           Sqrt[24304810001 + 
             200*Sqrt[1559]*(1/x)^(3/2)*(50 + 155901*x) + 
             (2500 + 31180100 x)/x^2]];

mx = 4; (* number of sections *)
nMin = NMinValue[{expr, 5 <= x <= 500}, x]; (* corrected *)
nMax = NMaxValue[{expr, 5 <= x <= 500}, x]; (* corrected *)

subRanges = Partition[Subdivide[nMin, nMax, mx], 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{0.0636035, 0.205906}, {0.205906, 0.348208}, 
>  {0.348208, 0.49051}, {0.49051, 0.632812}}
> ```

```
Column[
   Plot[expr, {x, 5, 500},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, #},
     AxesLabel -> {x, SuperStar[E]},
     ImageSize -> 300] & 
   /@ Reverse @ subRanges]
```

[image: plots]

#### Update

I'm not sure which midpoints you are asking about, but guessing it is the midpoints of the sub-ranges, the code would go like this:

```
midY = Mean /@ subRanges;
midX = (NSolve[expr == #, x] & /@ midY)[[All, 1, 1, 2]]
midPts = {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[#]} & /@ Transpose[{midX, midY}]

Column[
  MapThread[
    Plot[expr, {x, 5, 500},
      Epilog -> #1,
      PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, #2},
      AxesLabel -> {x, SuperStar[E]},
      ImageSize -> 300] &, 
    Reverse /@ {midPts, subRanges}]]
```

[image: plots]

#### Update 2

Another reading of question is that you want everything to be drawn on one plot. This is easy, too.

This is to show where the segment boundaries are.

```
dividers = {Dashed, HalfLine[{{0, #}, {500, #}}] & /@ subRanges[[2 ;;, 1]]};

Plot[expr, {x, 5, 500},
  Epilog -> {midPts, dividers},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {nMin, nMax}},
  AxesLabel -> {x, SuperStar[E]},
  ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update 3

To do what you ask for in your comment to this answer, you need to compute sub-domains as well as sub-ranges.

```
subDomains = 
  Partition[
    Reverse[(Solve[expr == #, x] & /@ Subdivide[nMin, nMax, mx])[[All, 1, 1, 2]]], 
    2, 1];
```

and then make the plot with

```
Column[
  MapThread[
    Plot[expr, Prepend[#2, x],
      Epilog -> #1,
      PlotRange -> {0, 1},
      AxesLabel -> {x, SuperStar[E]},
      ImageSize -> 300] &, 
    {Reverse[midPts], subDomains}]]
```

which gives

[image: plot4]

I find this a rather strange way to present the segmentation of the curve, but if it suits you, then fine.

Comment: Wow! I can't thank you enough for the answer. I have a question about this section here where 

`midY = Mean /@ subRanges;
midX = (NSolve[expr == #, x] & /@ midY)[[All, 1, 1, 2]]
midPts = {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[#]} & /@ Transpose[{midX, midY}]

Column[
  MapThread[
    Plot[expr, {x, 5, 500},
      Epilog -> #1,
      PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, #2},
      AxesLabel -> {x, SuperStar[E]},
      ImageSize -> 300] &, 
    Reverse /@ {midPts, subRanges}]]`

How do I set the PlotRange for the y-axis to be constant {0,1} for all the plot generated?

Comment: @AhmadRuzaini禅. I have updated the answer once again to answer the issue you bring up in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [same pre-amble](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148778/1997) as @m_goldberg, to illustrate use of [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html):

```
s[x1_, x2_, n_] := 
 With[{r = Range[x1, x2, (x2 - x1)/n]}, {r, MovingAverage[r, 2]}]
Plot[expr, {x, 0, 500}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {#2}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}, GridLines -> {None, #1}, 
   PlotRange -> {#1[[1]], #1[[-1]]}] & @@ s[nMin, nMax, mx]
```

[image]